# How to measure output DC impedance of clock oscillator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator, circuit-design, oscilloscope, impedance

I need to accurately measure the **DC** impedance of a clock oscillator's (single-ended) output buffer. What are some ways I can tackle this in the lab?

If it helps, I have an oscilloscope (but not a VNA). I'm looking for practical test setups, with or without the scope.

Comment: What frequency is the clock?

Comment: When designing test procedures for hardware validation, it is important to remember that specifications are usually written by English majors with no clue about electronics, and you need to follow common sense regarding some wordings. So don't take the "DC" too literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would load it with various resistors in series with a cap to GND and measure output voltage variations in the flat part of the waveform.

Responding to your edit:

If the spec is concerned with output impedance, then it is all about transmission lines and reflections, and what matters is the output impedance of the buffer on both signal levels. You can use the method I suggested to measure it.

Comment: That won't tell you how far you can pull the average dc value of the output.

Comment: OP needs to define exactly what he needs to measure, then. Since the DC impedance of a buffer is its output resistance when outputting a constant level, I proposed this as a workaround to the fact the buffer is constantly switching. If OP wants to measure the shift in average output voltage when a DC current is applied, then this would not work.

Comment: I can only go on what is stated. If he meant AC then he wouldn't have made "DC" in bold text. That's how I read it anyway.

Comment: Thanks @peufeu, What purpose does the series cap to ground serve (if the cap is in series with the load, won't it block DC flowing through the load)?

Comment: Instead of using a cap, you can put the resistor across output and GND, then measure impedance on high level. Then put resistor between output and VCC, and measure impedance on low level. Cap will hold a VCC/2 DC value, so it allows to measure both.